# How to add text editor in plugin menu?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, admin-menu

Can I add a **text editor to my plugin menu**? So I can let users edit custom css file? Something like `/wp-admin/plugin-editor.php` but I want users to be able to edit only one file. The custome css file.

Could this be done using **Wordpress standard functions**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you

http://keighl.com/2010/01/tinymce-in-wordpress-plugins/

Comment: Looks promising, just thinking if I need tinymce it I need to edit css file.